# How does Google Analytics filters duplicate site entrances

Tags: google-analytics

We are implementing a native analytics system and want to apply the same tracking principles Google Analytics uses. We've figured everything out but one thing:

Every time I refresh a page with an url that has utm-parameters attached to it, Google Analytics somehow figures out that it's not actually a visit but the same page that gets refreshed and shows only one visit in its dashboard from that particular source.

Is anybody aware how GA specifically does that so I can replicate it in our system?

I know that I can use

```
performance.navigation.type
```

in my JS script, but it doesn't give me desired results.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribution in GA happens on the Google servers, so JavaScript will be of limited use. Basically since a reload means that the user has the same client id and no change in the channel (source, medium and campaign are the same as in the previous visit) the existing session will be continued (a change of campaign/source information would trigger a new Google Analytics session).

[Google has a very nice chart](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762?hl=en#flowchart) that explains how campaign information and traffic source information is processed.

Comment: Thank. It's exactly what I was searching for.